# How to get the all the record with out removing in Group in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working with attendance management system. I have to prepare some report punch report with include all the finger print record of the each employee. I want crate table which show date and all the time relevant to that date. Using following query I got result like that

```
SELECT * FROM `attendancedata` where `EnrolledID`= 23 GROUP BY 
Date,EnrolledID,Time ORDER BY Date DESC,Time DESC


EnrolledID  Date    Time    
23  2019-09-09  07:58:36
23  2019-09-07  17:25:00    
23  2019-09-07  16:08:27    
23  2019-09-07  07:32:39    
23  2019-09-06  16:00:10    
23  2019-09-06  07:48:51    
23  2019-09-05  16:00:23    
23  2019-09-05  07:40:55    
23  2019-09-04  16:00:39    
23  2019-09-04  07:45:42    
23  2019-09-03  16:00:06    
23  2019-09-03  07:43:32    
23  2019-09-02  16:00:04    
23  2019-09-02  07:56:25
```

my expected result is

```
Date        P01       P02       P03    P04     P05    P06    P07
2019-09-02  07:56:25  16:00:04
2019-09-03  07:43:32  16:00:06
2019-09-04  07:45:42  16:00:39
2019-09-05  07:40:55  16:00:23
2019-09-06  07:48:51  16:00:10
2019-09-07  07:32:39  16:08:27 17:25:00
2019-09-08  07:58:36
```

how do i solve this problem? (punch time limit to maximum 7 time)
(using query or using php)

Comment: And what if the number of times relevant to specific date will be more than 5?

Comment: maximum 7 time bro

Comment: Try MySQL variable to do `ranking` and then use `case when`.

Comment: @NipunSachinda, verify my answer, it will work for MySQL 5.7 or lesser version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the exact same attendance data table and I have made a few queries to retrieve the end result similar to what you need. Try this one below:

```
SELECT EnrolledID,DATE,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeAttList,' ',1) AS 'P01',
       CASE WHEN TotalCheckin >=2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeAttList,' ',2),' ',-1) END AS 'P02',
       CASE WHEN TotalCheckin >=3 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeAttList,' ',3),' ',-1) END AS 'P03',
       CASE WHEN TotalCheckin >=4 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeAttList,' ',4),' ',-1) END AS 'P04',
       CASE WHEN TotalCheckin >=5 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeAttList,' ',5),' ',-1) END AS 'P05',
       CASE WHEN TotalCheckin >=6 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeAttList,' ',6),' ',-1) END AS 'P06',
       CASE WHEN TotalCheckin =7 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(TimeAttList,' ',7),' ',-1) END AS 'P07'
FROM
(SELECT EnrolledID,DATE,GROUP_CONCAT(TIME ORDER BY TIME ASC SEPARATOR ' ') AS 'TimeAttList',COUNT(*) AS 'TotalCheckin'
   FROM `attendancedata` 
  WHERE `EnrolledID`= 1
GROUP BY EnrolledID, DATE ORDER BY DATE ASC,TIME ASC) A;
```

I'm using MySQL 4.1.
What I did is first I use `GROUP_CONCAT` with `ORDER BY` inside it. This will list all the time as following:

```
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
| EnrolledID |    Date    |                      TimeAttList                      | TotalCheckin |
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|          1 | 2019-06-24 | 08:53:01 12:02:17 12:35:33 18:04:57                   |            4 |
|          1 | 2019-06-25 | 09:01:13 12:00:13 12:59:23 18:17:32                   |            4 |
|          1 | 2019-06-26 | 08:54:10 12:03:32 13:00:37 18:03:56                   |            4 |
|          1 | 2019-06-27 | 08:53:46 12:01:49 12:56:30 18:17:31                   |            4 |
|          1 | 2019-06-28 | 08:59:31 11:03:31 11:58:59 17:03:10 17:58:31 21:05:58 |            6 |
|          1 | 2019-06-29 | 08:58:50 11:01:54 11:59:51 17:05:01 18:01:05 21:08:48 |            6 |
|          1 | 2019-06-30 | 09:01:13 11:00:49 12:00:03 17:04:42 18:00:17 20:14:28 |            6 |
|          1 | 2019-07-01 | 10:53:00 15:04:06 16:01:18 20:00:21                   |            4 |
+------------+------------+-------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
```

I make the base to become sub-query then I use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to separate the `GROUP_CONCAT` results:

```
+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
| EnrolledID |    DATE    |   P01    |   P02    |   P03    |   P04    |   P05    |   P06    | P07 |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
|          1 | 2019-06-24 | 08:53:01 | 12:02:17 | 12:35:33 | 18:04:57 |          |          |     |
|          1 | 2019-06-25 | 09:01:13 | 12:00:13 | 12:59:23 | 18:17:32 |          |          |     |
|          1 | 2019-06-26 | 08:54:10 | 12:03:32 | 13:00:37 | 18:03:56 |          |          |     |
|          1 | 2019-06-27 | 08:53:46 | 12:01:49 | 12:56:30 | 18:17:31 |          |          |     |
|          1 | 2019-06-28 | 08:59:31 | 11:03:31 | 11:58:59 | 17:03:10 | 17:58:31 | 21:05:58 |     |
|          1 | 2019-06-29 | 08:58:50 | 11:01:54 | 11:59:51 | 17:05:01 | 18:01:05 | 21:08:48 |     |
|          1 | 2019-06-30 | 09:01:13 | 11:00:49 | 12:00:03 | 17:04:42 | 18:00:17 | 20:14:28 |     |
|          1 | 2019-07-01 | 10:53:00 | 15:04:06 | 16:01:18 | 20:00:21 |          |          |     |
+------------+------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: much helpful and its working .thank you for valuable contribution

Comment: You're welcome @NipunSachinda . Just coincidence that we have the same table structrure and requirement.

Comment: @tvadidot0, nice one, definitely simpler format to understand. Couldn't resist myself to do voteup.

Comment: Thanks @JitendraYadav . I thought your solution works well and I'm actually in the middle of trying your query and see if will fit my condition. Your query is much shorter than what I have and I might be able to make it even shorter.

Comment: For performance, yes. Bcz `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is costly and you are using it more. In my query simple variable doing the job and `CASE WHEN` for extracting data. TRY both solution and let us know, how both are behaving with large dataset.

Comment: Out of 4 testing I did on a remote server (ping latency around 3ms), I found that the query with `SUBSTRING_INDEX` is faster in 1.489 second on average. I did another test with MySQL flush before executing each query and the difference increased - `SUBSTRING_INDEX` was faster by 14.208 secs - 292,871 rows > output 68,824 rows. On a different remote server (ping latency around 16ms), the `CASE` query perform faster by 8.109 seconds (1 test) - 437,793 rows > output 101,329 rows (larger data). I'm checking whether the table index is different between both server.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MySQL 8+, we can handle this using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Date ORDER BY Time) rn
    FROM attendancedata
    WHERE EnrolledID = 23
)

SELECT
    Date,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN Time END) AS PO1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN Time END) AS PO2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN Time END) AS PO3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN Time END) AS PO4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN Time END) AS PO5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 6 THEN Time END) AS PO6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 7 THEN Time END) AS PO7
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Date
ORDER BY
    Date;
```

But note that in general it is desirable to store date and time in a single `datetime` field with MySQL.  In this particular case, it worked out well, but this may not always be true.

Comment: this query not working to me.WITH key word not recognition statement error coming .i think version of the mysql is problem.

Comment: You can't easily do this in MySQL without using `ROW_NUMBER`.

Answer (score 3):

**MySQL 5.7 & Lower**:

- Use MySQL Variable to do the ranking based on `date` and `time`. We already assumed that it is for one user only.
- Use `CASE WHEN` on the derived result through `aggregation` and split info in 7 columns.

```
SELECT 
    t.`Date`,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 1 THEN t.`Time` END) AS PO1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 2 THEN t.`Time` END) AS PO2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 3 THEN t.`Time` END) AS PO3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 4 THEN t.`Time` END) AS PO4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 5 THEN t.`Time` END) AS PO5,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 6 THEN t.`Time` END) AS PO6,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rank = 7 THEN t.`Time` END) AS PO7
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.`Date`,
        a.`Time`,
        IF(@old_date = a.`Date`, @rank:= @rank + 1, @rank:= 1) AS rank, -- Assigning ranks
        @old_date:= a.`Date`
    FROM attendancedata a, 
    (SELECT @old_date:= '0000-00-00' AS o_d, @rank:= 0 AS r) dt
    WHERE a.EnrolledId = 23  -- Picking only data for user 23
    ORDER By `Date`, `Time`  -- Make sure to do sorting, based on sorted data, ranking will appear.
) AS t
GROUP BY t.`Date`
ORDER BY t.`Date`;
```

Comment: i think this solved my problem.when i check query and i will mark as correct answer .much appreciate your valuable help

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to group by dates. You can try this

```
SELECT Date, JSON_ARRAYAGG(Time) as times FROM attendancedata GROUP BY Date.
```

Comment: what is meaning of JSON_ARRAYAGG

Comment: Refer this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg

Comment: JSON_ARRAYAGG does not exist .

Comment: It will available in MySQL 5.7+. Which versiion are you using ?

Comment: 4.8.5 version i used