# How can I group by different responsibles names for the same ID

Tags: mysql

Let me explain what I need: I have different name_user for a unique num_contract, however, it is showing one responsible by row.

```
SELECT a.num_contract, g.name_user
FROM `contract` AS a
INNER JOIN `resp_contract` g ON g.id_contract = a.id_contract
INNER JOIN `user` h ON h.id_user = g.id_user
ORDER BY `a`.`id_contract` DESC
```

OUTPUT

```
a.num_contract | g.name_user
0857             John
0857             Mark
0856             Ann
0855             Louis
0855             Peter
0855             Alisson
```

As you can see above, a.num_contract is unique and showing the name_user in each row.

What I expect:

```
a.num_contract | g.name_user
0857             John, Mark
0856             Ann
0855             Louis, Peter, Alisson
```

OR

```
a.num_contract | g.name_user | g.name_user | g.name_user
0857             John          Mark          NULL
0856             Ann           NULL          NULL  
0855             Louis         Peter         Alisson
```

I read something about pivot table, but I'm not sure how I can achieve it. 
Thank you,

Comment: For 1st output look at [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When wanting user list as a single column, you can use `GROUP_BY` with `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT 
    a.num_contract AS Contract_No, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(g.name_user) AS Users
FROM `contract` AS a
INNER JOIN `resp_contract` g ON g.id_contract = a.id_contract
INNER JOIN `user` h ON h.id_user = g.id_user
GROUP BY a.num_contract
ORDER BY `a`.`id_contract` DESC;

Output:
Contract_No    | Users
--------------------------------------
0857           | John,Mark
0856           | Ann
0855           | Louis,Peter,Alisson
```

If you want to list the users as separate column then you can use `rank` variable or `SUBSTRING_INDEX` on above query to get the desired result.

```
SELECT
    Contract_No,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(Users,'$$',1) AS User_1,
    CASE WHEN Total_Users >=2 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Users,'$$',2),' ',-1) END AS User_2,
    CASE WHEN Total_Users>=3 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Users, '$$',3),' ',-1) END AS User_3
FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.num_contract AS Contract_No, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(g.name_user SEPARATOR '$$') AS Users,
        COUNT(0) AS Total_Users
    FROM `contract` AS a
    INNER JOIN `resp_contract` g ON g.id_contract = a.id_contract
    INNER JOIN `user` h ON h.id_user = g.id_user
    GROUP BY a.num_contract
    ORDER BY `a`.`id_contract` DESC
) AS t;

Output:
Contract_No    | User_1      | User_2     | User_3
-----------------------------------------------------
0857           | John        | Mark       |  
0856           | Ann         |            |
0855           | Louis       | Peter      |  Alisson
```

Comment: You can also use MySQL variable to this do this job. Check answer given by me in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864123/how-to-get-the-all-the-record-with-out-removing-in-group-in-mysql/57864792#57864792